# Divide the cell content into separate rows in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to split the cell content with length greater than 72 into separate rows with their length not increasing more than 72 chars. I am not able to thing through this logic and need help. 
Special challenge here is that the content of each cell is is a complete sentence and has no delimiter, so I need to divide the statement only when a word ends and also having length 72 chars preserved for each cell and not more than that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide sample cell data? A split on full stops, if you have them, seems a possible way to go.  Also, you'll get a better response if you add what you've tried already.

Comment: Not sure if this can be done using formulas. But it can be easily accomplished using VBA: with `split` using spaces as the delimiter and a `For...Next` loop going through the resulting array.

Comment: @Ambie Hi, You can assume any sentence having length greater than 72 chars. Let's assume the length of sentence is 84 chars so now the quest is I need to automatically create a new row beneath this cell and divide this sentence into 2 parts - 72 char part & 12 char part, but challenging thing here is that division take care of the words and must not split them even if it takes to have cell1 value less than 72 and cell2 value  compensating for it.

Comment: @Ralph I tried using Split as well with space as delimiters but in vain as it divides the complete statement into separate words.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you'll need a loop afterwards to go through the array of resulting words. Given your above example you might get back 14 words (for example) on the 84 characters you mentioned. Now you loop through the array of 14 words and concatenate them back together keeping track of their `len`. Once you have bypassed 72 you take the latest addition out and paste it to the cell, move to the next row and continue with the array until it is empty. Done.

Comment: @Ralph That seems some serious programming, I may need help with this part I am not that strong here.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using regular expressions.  Try adapting this macro, which I wrote some time ago, to your specific requirements:  If a word should happen to be longer than `w` characters, it will overflow -- probably not a problem with 72 character line length; but you can change that behavior by changing the regex.

As written, the macro will write the split text into cells below the original.

---

```
Sub WordWrap()
'requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'Wraps at W characters, but will allow overflow if a word is longer than W
Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, m As Match
Dim str As String
Dim w As Long
Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range
Dim mBox As Long
Dim I As Long
'with offset as 1, split data will be below original data
'with offset = 0, split data will replace original data
Const lDestOffset As Long = 1

Set rSrc = Selection
    If rSrc.Rows.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox ("You may only select" & vbLf & " Data in One (1) Row")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Set RE = New RegExp
    RE.Global = True
w = InputBox("Maximum characters in a Line: ", , 72)
    If w < 1 Then w = 79
For Each C In rSrc
str = C.Value
'remove all line feeds and nbsp
    RE.Pattern = "[\xA0\r\n\s]+"
    str = RE.Replace(str, " ")
    RE.Pattern = "\S.{0," & w - 1 & "}(?=\s|$)|\S{" & w & ",}"
If RE.Test(str) = True Then
    Set MC = RE.Execute(str)
'see if there is enough room
I = lDestOffset + 1
Do Until I > MC.Count + lDestOffset
    If Len(C(I, 1)) <> 0 Then
        mBox = MsgBox("Data in " & C(I, 1).Address & " will be erased if you contine", vbOKCancel)
        If mBox = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    End If
I = I + 1
Loop

    I = lDestOffset
    For Each m In MC
        C.Offset(I, 0).Value = m
        I = I + 1
    Next m
End If
Next C
Set RE = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Example using your original post as the data in one cell:

[image]

Here is an explanation and links to explanations regarding the line-splitting regular expression, as it would be rendered with a line length of 72 characters.

### \S.{0,71}(?=\s|$)|\S{72,}

```
\S.{0,71}(?=\s|$)|\S{72,}
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks (irrelevant in this instance)

- [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\S.{0,71}(?=\s|$)`

  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S`
  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{0,71}`

    - [Between zero and 71 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{0,71}`
  - [Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\s|$)`

    - [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\s`

      - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
    - [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `$`

      - [Assert position at the end of a line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\S{72,}`

  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S{72,}`

    - [Between 72 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{72,}`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

**EDIT** At the request of the original poster, a routine was added which would cycle through the cells in column A, placing the results of the splitting into column B.  Some of the original code, allowing selection of line length and source selection, was hard-coded.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub WordWrap2()
'requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'Wraps at W characters, but will allow overflow if a word is longer than W
Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
Dim str As String
Const W As Long = 72
Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range
Dim vRes() As Variant
Dim I As Long

'Set source to column A
Set rSrc = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

Set RE = New RegExp
    RE.Global = True
    I = 0
    For Each C In rSrc
    str = C.Value

    'remove all line feeds and nbsp
    RE.Pattern = "[\xA0\r\n\s]+"
    str = RE.Replace(str, " ")
    RE.Pattern = "\S.{0," & W - 1 & "}(?=\s|$)|\S{" & W & ",}"

    If RE.Test(str) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(str)
        ReDim Preserve vRes(1 To MC.Count + I)
        For Each M In MC
            I = I + 1
            vRes(I) = M
        Next M
        Else  'Allow preservation of blank lines in source data
         I = I + 1
    End If
Next C

'if ubound(vres) > 16384 then will need to transpose in a loop
vRes = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vRes)

With Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vRes, 1))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

Set RE = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Comment: if I put in A2 `{=MID(A1,1,MAX(IF(MID(A1,ROW(1:72),1)=" ",ROW(1:72)))-1)}` and in A3 `{=IF((LEN($A$1)-FIND(A2,$A$1)-LEN(A2)-1)>72,MID(MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1)+LEN(A2)+1,9999),1,MAX(IF(MID(MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1)+LEN(A2)+1,999),ROW($1:$72),1)=" ",ROW($1:$72)))-1),MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1)+LEN(A2)+1,9999))}` and copy down A3 I get exactly the same ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel Impressive.  I'm sure it is effective but when I try to copy/paste your `A3` formula I get a `problem with your formula` error message.

Comment: worked perfectly for me... pls try this for A3: `{=IF((LEN($A$1)-SUM(LEN($A$2:A2)+1))>72,MID($A$1,1+SUM(LEN($A$2:A2))+ROWS($A$2:A2),MAX(IF(MID($A$1,ROW($1:$72)+SUM(LEN($A$2:A2))+ROWS($A$2:A2),1)=" ",ROW($1:$72)))-1),IF(LEN($A$1)<=SUM(LEN($A$2:A2)+1),"",MID($A$1,1+SUM(LEN($A$2:A2))+ROWS($A$2:A2),999)))}` and check for the *comments-add-invisible-characters-to-code-bug* ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel  Got it.  Your comment at the end, even without the link, was the clue.  There were two Unicode characters (apparently) in one of the function arguments.  Same problem with your second A3 formula.  I note that when trying to enter the formula, the cursor appears at the erroneous point, with the errant characters (which appear normal) in gray color (excel 2016).  Your second A3 formula is better in that it doesn't repeat.

Comment: The second formula also just goes for the count of letters while the first "searches" the text from above which may fail if 72+ letters repeat in the same order... still, it just shows the possibility of formulas and I wouldn't use it in cases like this... ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel I agree that with complicated formula and the occasional helper column, one can accomplish pretty complex operations; useful techniques if IT doesn't allow macros at work.

Comment: @DirkReichel By the way, the Unicode characters that crept in were `ZWNJ` (zero width non joiner) and `ZWSP` (zero width space).  Chars `U+200C` and `U+200B`  Why?  I dunno.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld DirkReichel Gentlemen you both are Excel demigods indeed... I tried and both are working as expected but may I bother you with a small hidden requirement... I have a column range of such statements and when I try to run the macros my other statements get over written. Can you help me with this part as well. I just want them to shift down when a previous statement is being disintegrated. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: @Monty. Do you want all of The Originals / written? Or would you prefer to have the split up information in an adjacent column?

Comment: @Monty the first question should be do you want the originals over written?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes Ron I would be perfectly ok with both the ways, whatever is easier to implement. Thanks for the response again:)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have a complete list of statements in a column in several rows. If this code above can help me to loop through the column and divide the statements while shifting other statements in the rows below without deleting them, it would serve the purpose

Comment: @Monty I won't have time to work on that for a few days.  As written, the macro will cycle through entries in a single **row**, not column, writing the results in the rows below. If your task is a one-time thing, you could transpose your data and use it as is.  If it needs to be repetitive, you could change the loop to cycle through a single column, and write the results in an adjacent column.  I'll check back when I am back home.

Comment: Thank You very much @RonRosenfeld ... I'll come clean that your code is beyond my regular VBA capabilities to be edited... I'll wait for you to return back :)

Comment: @Monty  Ok, the additional code shows one way of doing this.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you Ron, this code does exactly as you say but it also removes all the blank cells between the two such cells with chars>72. Can we have some mechanism to retain those blank spaces?

Comment: @Monty Sure.  Just add an `Else` to the `re.test...` to enlarge `vRes` by one, and add one to the value of `I`  Blank lines will cause the `re.test(...` test to return false, and you enlarge the results array (and also change the Index storage pointer) to produce a blank entry.  Try to do that, and post back with results and/or problems.

Comment: Thank You very much @RonRosenfeld I was able to achieve the results as desired, I've updated the code as you told. You are genius mind indeed. Thanks a ton again :)

Comment: @Monty I'm glad you were able to do that, and that I was able to explain it clearly enough so you could do it yourself, rather than just supplying code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I was thinking of playing around this code, can you guide me how can I repeat the serial number for each cell while dividing them into 72 chars. For example if I have a cell with 144 chars and serail number S1 assigned to it in another column, so when I use the above module to divide the text into 2 cells then the same Serial number S1 is also copied to each new cell created. Can we do it?

Comment: @Monty I would add an extra `column` to the results array `vRes` and put the serial number there.  See Chip Pearson's info on [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).  If you have problems, post a new question with code and examples of exactly what you want for output.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121820/divide-the-cell-content-into-separate-rows-along-with-corresponding-columns

Comment: @Monty In your new question, I do not see how you tried to modify the code to accomplish you goals; I do not see any sample data; I do not see how you want the results formatted.  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or your question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long, rowIdx As Long
    Dim myString As Variant
    str = " "
    myString = Split(Range("A1").Value)
    rowIdx = 5    '-->row number from where data will be displayed
    For i = LBound(myString) To UBound(myString)
        If (Len(str) + Len(myString(i)) + 1) > 72 Then '-->check for length > 72
            Range("A" & rowIdx).Value = Trim(str)      '-->if > 72 display in cell
            rowIdx = rowIdx + 1                        '-->increment row index
            str = ""                 'set str="" to countinue for new line
        End If
        str = str & myString(i) & " "
    Next
    If Len(str) > 0 Then Range("A" & rowIdx).Value = Trim(str) 'display remiaing words
End Sub
```

[image]